# news ticker jquery not running on dynamic content (repeater control)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have created one pane to show news as a ticker which is dynamic,i have bound repeater control to display news,i have used a jquery(vTicker) to slide news one by one.The jquery was running on static data but its not working when data made dynamic
 following is my code

```
   <div id="nt-title-container">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <ul id="ticker">
                            <li><a href="newsandevents.aspx" id="linkNews"><b>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("newsHeader") %>' CssClass="lblHeader"></asp:Label>
                            </b>
                                <br />
                                <small>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("newsDate") %>' CssClass="lblDate"></asp:Label>
                                </small>
                                <br />
                                <p>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("newsDescr") %>' CssClass="lblContent"></asp:Label>
                                </p>
                            </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
```

jquery:-------

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#ticker').vTicker();
        });
    </script>
```

please tell me what is wrong with it.

Comment: Check the id generated for <ul>

Comment: it is <ul id="ticker">

Answer (score 0):

Your front-end code needs to look like the following. Moving the beginning and end div and ul tags inside the header template and footer templates of the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div id="nt-title-container">
            <ul id="ticker">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <li><a href="newsandevents.aspx" id="linkNews"><b>
            <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("newsHeader") %>' CssClass="lblHeader"></asp:Label>
        </b>
            <br />
            <small>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("newsDate") %>' CssClass="lblDate"></asp:Label>
            </small>
            <br />
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("newsDescr") %>' CssClass="lblContent"></asp:Label>
            </p>
        </a></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
            </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You also need to modify your javascript to target the containing div as opposed to the  going by the vTicker example as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#nt-title-container').vTicker();
    });
</script>
```

This should get it working for you.

Comment: k let me try this out!!

Comment: no sir still its not working, i have imported jqury min file properly still its not working.

Comment: no not a single error!!! can you suggest me any other ticker to slide 1 news upward at a time on same code? like vTricker?

Comment: actually i dont remember from where i got that..its kinda same

Comment: Could you trying using that script or find out which script you are using? They each have different methods of use which will have different results.

Comment: hey, i solved it, actually another jquery was conflicting it, it was nivo slider and  jquery files wer conflicting vTicker jquery, i just replaced the source file to latest version of nivo slider, bt thanks for you cooperation !!